# How to flatten an Object of Objects into an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript

I have data in the form of an Object of Objects

```
{
  a: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  },
  b: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }
}
```

I would like to transform it into an Array of Objects, each Object being formed from the key and values of the original one. In my case `what` would hold the key, and `value_x` the content of `x` in the value (of the original object):

```
[{
  value_x: 1,
  what: "a"
}, {
  value_x: 10,
  what: "b"
}]
```

I can do that via

```js
o = {
  a: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  },
  b: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }
}
a = Object.entries(o).map(e => {
  return {
    what: e[0],
    value_x: e[1].x
  }
})
console.log(a)
```

It works but seem quite ugly. Coming from a Python background, I was hoping to be able to get directly the key and value elements via something like

```
a = Object.entries(o).map([k, v] => {return {what: k, value_x: v.x}})
```

or

```
a = Object.entries(o).map((k, v) => {return {what: k, value_x: v.x}})
```

but none of them work.

**Is there a better solution? (= more aligned with the language)**

Comment: `([k, v])` will work (both parentheses and brackets required)

Comment: `([what,{x:value_x}]) => ({what, value_x})`

Comment: `Object.entries(o).map(([what,{x}])=>({what, value_x:x}))`

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries for the nested object as well with a `flatMap` approach.

```js
const
    o = { a: { x: 1, y: 1 }, b: { x: 10, y: 10 } },
    a = Object
        .entries(o)
        .flatMap(([what, values]) => Object
            .entries(values)
            .map(([k, v]) => ({ what, [`value_${k}`]: v }))
        );

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  },
  b: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }
};

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([key,{x}])=>({value_x: x,what: key}))
);
```